# utf-8 characters in emacs (only in term/ansi-term/multi-term) do not appear

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh, utf-8

I cannot for the life of me get utf-8 characters to appear correctly in emacs term mode on osx. They either appear as empty spaces or "<00e3><0081><00af>". I can view them in text buffers fine. I have the following in my .emacs:

```
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

I've also tried switching fonts, but to no avail. Does any one have any suggestions? I don't have any problems with the identical setup in Ubuntu. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm using zsh?

Comment: Can you show the value of variable `(describe-variable 'default-terminal-coding-system)`?

Comment: The valuable of the variable  (describe-variable 'default-terminal-coding-system) is "utf-8"

Comment: In **\*terminal\*** buffer I have the value of command `echo $TERM` - eterm-color. And I have directory `~/.terminfo/e/` and the files `eterm-color*` are there. What about your config?

Comment: My term was xterm-256color, but I switched to eterm-color just to see what would happen, but nothing has changed. It seems that I can actually type utf-8 characters and have them show up in term, but there are some utf-8 characters in the zsh prompt string that will not show up. Is that a different issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting these values in your .zshenv

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

It can be a source of errors since in Linux distributions the correct values use lowercase  utf (e.g. `en_US.utf-8`)

To view all available locales use `locale -a`